# JavaScript JQuery manipulating strange array type from database

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working with an old legacy system, and upgrading to php 8, and adding new functions.

Originally after login, the login page redirects you to `dashboard.html`, but once dashboard loads, it goes to PHP to recover the session data with OS stored in database, the search is by the `session_id()`.

But the database gives this array

```
[{"session_data":"username = chronos;nome=> Pedro Henrique;email=> pedro.hsdeus@hotmail.com;senha=>ZmFzdDkwMDI=;data=> 25\/04\/2021;hora=> 18:02;uid=>e27fd9d043ec817b2f10ae59ad81b315;"}]
```

How to navigate by this using JQuery or JavaScript/JSON. The dashboard doesn't run any PHP code it is pure HTML and JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

First of all. It is still a JSON string. So parse it.

```
const array = JSON.parse(data);
```

Now it is an array containing an object with 1 field. Get its content with

```
const content = array[0].session_data;
```

The content can be split up by the semicolon

```
const parts = content.split(';');
```

Now you have an array. Each field contains 1 part of the string. With the application of `parts[index].substring()` you can get the actual values and build up an object.

For example:

```
const object = {
    username: parts[0].substring(parts[0].indexOf('='), parts[0].length), 
    name: parts[1].substring(parts[1].indexOf('=>'), parts[1].length),
    email: parts[2].substring(parts[2].indexOf('=>'), parts[2].length)
}
```

and so on